# Rest api issue after deploying react app to heoku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So basically with my app i have react js  and node js. Everything works fine but I have a section of the web app that makes a post request to the node backend to get data related to getting an array of items through the ebay api. This worked fine during development but when I tried to do the same thing after deployment, I  get a 404 error

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "https://udabasili.herokuapp.com/api/ebay", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
```

The client link is https://udabasili.herokuapp.com/
The server link is  https://ud-portfolio-app.herokuapp.com/

I even used postman to send a post request to the node domain deployed on heroku  and it works, so the problem seems to be from the react js app

The app is a quite big but basically i have the node and react on two different domains with  have the static.json linking the node serveri have deployed already to react js using proxy

The important sections of the app involved :

STATIC.JSON

```
{
"root":"build/",
"routes":{
    "/**":"index.html"
},
"proxies":{
    "/api/":{
        "origin":"https://ud-portfolio-app.herokuapp.com/"
    }
}
```

}

NODE.JS

```
 const express = require("express");
const app = express()
const path = require("path")
const Ebay = require('ebay-node-api');
const cors = require("cors")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;

let access_token = '';
let ebay = new Ebay({
    clientID: '******************',
    clientSecret: '*******************',
    body: {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        scope: 'https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope'

    }
});


app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// An api endpoint that returns a short list of items
app.post('/api/ebay', (req,res) => {
    const item = req.body.itemName;
    ebay.findItemsByKeywords({
            keywords: `${item} movie`,
            }).then((data) => {
                res.json(data[0].searchResult[0].item);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
});


app.listen(PORT);
```

REST API SECTION

At this section I fetch the two apis . The youtube one work but the ebay has the 404 error

```
    function fetchProducts(name) {
    const itemName = name;
    const ebayApi = fetch("/api/ebay",
                    {
                      method: "POST",
                      cache: "no-cache",
                      headers:{
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                          },
                      body:JSON.stringify({itemName:itemName})
                    }
                  );
   const youtubeApi = fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=${name}%20movie%20trailer&key=**************`);
  return (dispatch) => {
    Promise.all([ebayApi, youtubeApi])
      .then( values =>  Promise.all(values.map(value =>{
        console.log(value);
        return value.json()})

        ))

      .then(res => {

        const youtube = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${res[1].items[0].id.videoId}?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&rel=0`;
        return (res[0], res[1].items[0].id.videoId)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
}

export default fetchProducts;
```

CLIENT PACKAGE.JSON

```
    {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8081",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "d3": "^5.12.0",
    "ebay-node-api": "^2.7.2",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.4.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "topojson-client": "^3.0.1",
    "youtube-api-search": "^0.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: 404 response means forbidden. Are you using the right API keys? It could be a CORS issue with the Ebay API specifically, even though you have it enabled on your app. Is there any more information in the network response?

Comment: Response {type: "basic", url: "https://udabasili.herokuapp.com/api/ebay", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
If it was a cors issue, wont that has come up in develoment ?

Comment: You can use the proxy layer by creating a route server side like this https://gist.github.com/pajaydev/b10b4d29bae85b441954d298a9e0d2c3 If you still face an issue kindly create issue here https://github.com/pajaydev/ebay-node-api